# layout messes up in internet explorer but fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsfiddle

I am having a major problem with my layout.

Using IE9 the layout messes up while the layout that in all other major browsers (chrome, safari, opera and Firefox) the layout is fine, no problems. What is causing the layout to mess up in IE9?

Here is jsfiddle embedded to show code and layout: http://jsfiddle.net/gRdGx/1/

The jsfiddle is justt here to show that it displays the features side by side and that is the layout I want for all my browsers, but as I have already stated the only browser it is not doing this in is `IE`.

Below is a screenshot showing the layout it is showing in IE 9 and in other browsers:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It could be due to a compatibility issue that maybe causing this. If so does anyone know how to change code slightly in order to get layout to work for IE9 and its older versions of 6/7/8?

Comment: my internet explorer shows fine in the fiddle

Comment: are you sure that you use correct browser settings for ie9? not ie7 compability mode?

Comment: @FredrickGauss Yes because it is in a fiddle, not actually in the internet explorer itself. Try posting the code in a script and upload script and viewing in IE and see if layout if fine or not.

Comment: @PaperThick I should tell you this, at home the layout is fine in IE9, it is just that at the university computer the layout messes up. Now my compatability is off for IE9 at home. But in university computer it does not display the compatiability symbol in url bar. How can I get that to appear to test it?

Comment: @PaperThick Is it is compatibility issue, is there a way to get it working in both IE9 and the older versions of 6,7,8 or am I clutching at straws? and when I ask this I meant do you know how to get it working in older versions of IE?

Comment: @Manixman If you're using ie7 the property inline-block is not fully supported, so that's the problem

Comment: is doctype property declared at the top?

Comment: @Manixman Someone will probably have a problem with this, but if ie7 and older is the issue, don't bother. < 1% is using ie7 so it's not worth the trouble in my opinion

Comment: try this link http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/12/12/how-to-fix-the-ie7-and-inline-block-css-bug/

Comment: @FredrickGauss There is a doctype at top, an answer has already mentioned this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this IE7 fix for `inline-block` on tables where you used it:

```
TABLE_ID{
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML in the fiddle I found:

```
<table class="answerSection">
    <tr>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
</table>
```

As this is not valid HTML it´s up to the browser to make the best of it. Could this be the source of the error?

1. First rule of HTML authoring: We always validate our HTML
2. Second rule of HTML authoring: We **always** validate our HTML

Comment: It doesn't show this in validator strangley enough, I will test this after I come back from picking my bro up

Answer (score 0):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the very to of your html.

This will turn your IE to manage the page as the most of the others.

Comment: thanks for info on that. Realised library computers don't have filezilla so can't upload files. Need to switch computers so I will test it when I switch computers